# Helmholtz equality

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the following PDE. We have that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ where

$$\lambda f - \frac{1}{2} \Delta f=0$$

with boundary conditions

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)\Bigg|_{x=0} &= c_1 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Bigg|_{y=0} &= c_2 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Bigg|_{x=1} &= c_3
\end{align}

It doesn't matter which values the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ have, but $c_3 > 0$ must be fixed.

Nothing I tried went in some useful direction, so I would be very glad if someone has an idea how to handle this problem.

Best Regards!

Comment: @Mattos You missed the location of third B.C. I've edited it back in